# How to specify timeout function for stream.read?

Tags: vb.net

```
        Try
            Do
                read = stream.Read(datain, 0, datain.Length)
                responseData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(datain, 0, read)
                finalResponse = finalResponse + responseData
            Loop While read > 0
        Catch ex As Exception
```

Sometimes the program is stuck at that stream.read If it fails I want to moveon.

How to fix that?

Comment: What type is `stream`?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the readtimeout value for the stream.

```
stream.BaseStream.ReadTimeout = 1000
```

You can readup on the property [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.readtimeout%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on MSDN

Answer (score 0):

you have to use stream.ReadTimeout(time in milliseconds)

And you have to use a try catch agains TimeOutException

```
Try
            stream.ReadTimeout(5000);
            Do
     try
     {
                read = stream.Read(datain, 0, datain.Length)
                responseData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(datain, 0, read)
                finalResponse = finalResponse + responseData
     }
     catch err as TimeoutException
     { 
          read = 1; //To avoid quiting the loop
     }
            Loop While read > 0
        Catch ex As Exception
```

Perhaps my syntax is not perfect as i code in c# but the sollution still the same for both languages.